# Convert a column value in SHA256 in bash

Tags: sha256

I have a big csv file delimited with "|". How do I encrypt the 2nd column value into SHA256 using bash for full file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got answer for this:  for data in `cat test.txt`; do d1=$(echo $data | cut -d "|" -f1); d2=$(echo $data | cut -d "|" -f2 | sha256sum); rest=$(echo $data | cut -d "|" -f3-); echo "$d1|$d2|$rest";done >> new_file.txt

Answer (score 0):

for data in `cat test.txt`; do d1=$(echo $data | cut -d "|" -f1); d2=$(echo $data | cut -d "|" -f2 | sha256sum); rest=$(echo $data | cut -d "|" -f3-); echo "$d1|$d2|$rest";done >> new_file.txt